# How do I add a second Controller to an existing Model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a single model that I want to expose through two sets of views, and perform logic differently depending on which view is being used.

An example of this might be having one controller/view set for providing a web interface, and another controller/view set for providing a Desktop or Mobile or some other type of interface.

This is a 2-part question:

1) Is it "okay" stylistically to have multiple controllers that share a model?

2) How exactly would I go about adding another controller to an existing model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need one or two actions, I would recommend keeping it all in the same controller. No need to make things overly complex. If you need a full set of REST actions for each controller, here is an example of how I would do it:

Lets say you are running a events site that also has groups. Events can be created, edited etc in the context of a group, or completely on their own. Lets look at a couple URLs that would need full REST actions for each:

```
/groups/1/events  # Lists all events associated with a group
/events           # Lists all events
```

Setup the routes this way:

```
resources :events
resources :groups do
  resources :events, :controller => 'groups/events'
end
```

You will now have two controllers. One lives in `app/controllers/events_controller.rb` and the other in `app/controllers/groups/events_controller.rb`

The last important detail is to namespace the second controller:

```
class Groups::EventsController < ApplicationController
```

You can do this using rails built in generators:

```
rails g controller 'groups/events'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's okay--if they're so different that just adding actions to one doesn't separate them enough technically or cognitively, why not?

There are different ways you could configure it; the [routing guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) goes over them all--which to use depends on a variety of factors.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is the views, a given controller can render different views.  RoR is RESTfull  so you can make your controller render views based on what the client asked for (FAT, Mobile or web).

If you have very different logic, then yeah you can have another controller over a model object.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the css depending on the clients widget to have a better fit of your site for smartphones, Touchpads,... I would suggest you to read sth. about the media option while including stylesheets:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html